# Restric login Office 365 from Outside Company Network

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365

currently i'm in the middle of Implement Office 365 in my Company.

i have some issue about how to Restric user to login Office 365 from Outside Office Network or Allowed Device in Phone.

currently we have Active Directory (not Azure AD) implemented in all Office's PC.

My question is how to implement rule/restric user to not login Office 365 outside office network / allowed Device in Phone.

my Goal : prevent user to open email in their own device and download Company Data (Data Leaking).

Note : i need other solution except Azure Directory cause we don't have more budget to invest in Azure AD.

Thankyou

Comment: Aliga, you're asking about a free service that would replace paid functionality of the Azure AD. This isn't a question that can be solved here. See [azure ad pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use office 365 it includes Azure Active Directory. The best way to achieve your requirement is via Conditional Access policy. In order to apply Conditional Access policy you need to have a premium Azure Active Directory license. If you need to achieve above scenario without Azure Active Directory along with iPhone access kindly check any MDM services and see if it helps.